# Fix for Ssl Asynchronous Client in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, asynchronous, client

I'm attempting to write a .Net Framework 4.7.2 client that can communicate with a proto buffer payload eventually, over SSL.  I think the best approach would be a TAP model, but I've had less luck finding a working example to repeatedly do the send (if data to send) and process server messages as and when the server replies, and therefore I've gone with the APM approach here below.

My problem is I get a "The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write is pending" error in SendWorker().  My server does receive the connection and the message. I can work on the SSL cert later.

My output is:

```
Client connected.
Client is selecting a local certificate.
To quit, press the enter key.
Client is selecting a local certificate.
Validating the server certificate.
Certificate error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
Writing data to the server.
Writing data to the server.
```

The test code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace SslClient
{
    // This is a client side of a
    // client-server application that communicates using the
    // SslStream and TcpClient classes.
    // After connecting to the server and authenticating,
    // the client should repeatedly send items from a q and listen for any replies
    public class SslTcpClient
    {
        // complete is used to terminate the application when all
        // asynchronous calls have completed or any call has thrown an exception.
        // complete might be used by any of the callback methods.
        private bool complete = false;
        // e stores any exception thrown by an asynchronous method so that
        // the mail application thread can display the exception and terminate gracefully.
        // e might be used by any of the callback methods.
        private Exception e = null;

        // readData and buffer holds the data read from the server.
        // They is used by the ReadCallback method.
        private StringBuilder readData = new StringBuilder();
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        EventWaitHandle _trigger = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private TcpClient _tcpClient;
        private SslStream _sslStream;

        private Thread _senderThread;
        private readonly object _locker = new object();
        public ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> WriteQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();


        // The following method is invoked by the CertificateValidationDelegate.
        public bool ValidateServerCertificate(
              object sender,
              X509Certificate certificate,
              X509Chain chain,
              SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validating the server certificate.");
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);
            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return true;        // ToDo
        }


        public X509Certificate SelectLocalCertificate(
            object sender,
            string targetHost,
            X509CertificateCollection localCertificates,
            X509Certificate remoteCertificate,
            string[] acceptableIssuers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client is selecting a local certificate.");
            if (acceptableIssuers != null &&
                acceptableIssuers.Length > 0 &&
                localCertificates != null &&
                localCertificates.Count > 0)
            {
                // Use the first certificate that is from an acceptable issuer.
                foreach (X509Certificate certificate in localCertificates)
                {
                    string issuer = certificate.Issuer;
                    if (Array.IndexOf(acceptableIssuers, issuer) != -1)
                        return certificate;
                }
            }
            if (localCertificates != null &&
                localCertificates.Count > 0)
                return localCertificates[0];
            return null;
        }


        private void AuthenticateCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SslStream stream = (SslStream)ar.AsyncState;
            try

            {
                stream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception authenticationException)
            {
                e = authenticationException;
                //complete = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        public void ProduceConsumerQueue(TcpClient tcpClient, SslStream sslStream)
        {
            _tcpClient = tcpClient;
            _sslStream = sslStream;
            _senderThread = new Thread(SenderWorker);
            _senderThread.Start();
        }

        public void Send(byte[] payload)
        {
            WriteQueue.Enqueue(payload);
            _trigger.Set();
        }

        //our workhorse. This will just sit and wait until there is something to send  
        //it will continue to send until there is nothing left  
        void SenderWorker()
        {
            while (!complete)
            {
                string msg = null;
                if (WriteQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    byte[] message;
                    WriteQueue.TryDequeue(out message);

                    if (_tcpClient.Connected && message.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (_sslStream.CanWrite)
                        {
                            _sslStream.BeginWrite(message, 0, message.Length,
                                new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback),
                                _sslStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _trigger.WaitOne();     // Zero msgs left.. just wait   
                }
            }
        }

        private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SslStream stream = (SslStream)ar.AsyncState;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Writing data to the server.");
                stream.EndWrite(ar);

                // Asynchronously read a message from the server.
                //stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
                //    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback),
                //    stream);
            }
            catch (Exception writeException)
            {
                e = writeException;
                complete = true;
                return;
            }
        }


        private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Read the  message sent by the server.
            // The end of the message is signaled using the
            // "<EOF>" marker.
            SslStream stream = (SslStream)ar.AsyncState;
            int byteCount = -1;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading data from the server.");
                byteCount = stream.EndRead(ar);
                // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8
                // in case a character spans two buffers.
                Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, byteCount)];
                decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, byteCount, chars, 0);
                readData.Append(chars);
                // Check for EOF or an empty message.
                if (byteCount != 0)
                {
                    // We are not finished reading.
                    // Asynchronously read more message data from  the server.
                    stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback),
                        stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message from the server: {0}", readData.ToString());
                }

                if (WriteQueue.Count>0)
                {
                    //byte[] message;
                    //WriteQueue.TryDequeue(out message);

                    //if (message.Length > 0)
                    //{
                    //    stream.BeginWrite(message, 0, message.Length,
                    //        new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback),
                    //        ar);
                    //}
                }
            }
            catch (Exception readException)
            {
                e = readException;
                complete = true;
                return;
            }
            complete = true;
        }


        public int Main(string serverName, int port)
        {
            // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverName, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(SelectLocalCertificate)
                );

            var clientCertificate = FindClientCertificate(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "IIS Express Development Certificate");  // IIS Express Development Certificate
            var clientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection(new X509Certificate[] { clientCertificate });

            // Begin authentication.
            // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
            sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(
                "UIClient",
                clientCertificates,
                SslProtocols.Tls12,
                false,/* cert revocation */
                new AsyncCallback(AuthenticateCallback),
                sslStream);

            //            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("UIClient", clientCertificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
            ProduceConsumerQueue(client, sslStream);

            // User can press a key to exit application, or let the
            // asynchronous calls continue until they complete.
            Console.WriteLine("To quit, press the enter key.");
            do
            {
                // Real world applications would do work here
                // while waiting for the asynchronous calls to complete.
                Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello".ToArray()));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            } while (complete != true && Console.KeyAvailable == false);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Quitting.");
                client.Close();
                sslStream.Close();
                return 1;
            }
            if (e != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Good bye.");
            return 0;
        }

        private static X509Certificate FindClientCertificate(X509FindType type, string item)
        {
            return Find(type, item, StoreLocation.CurrentUser) ?? Find(type, item, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        }
        private static X509Certificate Find(X509FindType t, string item, StoreLocation location)
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(location))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                var certs = store.Certificates.Find(t, item, true);
                if (t == X509FindType.FindBySubjectName)
                {
                    return store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FriendlyName == item);
                }
                return certs.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

How can it be fixed? Is there a better complete solution that you can share?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: SSL is obsolete so I assume are really using TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Most servers two years ago SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 were all disabled.  TLS is performed at beginning of an HTTP.  A request will not be sent until TLS is successfully finished.  I would use a sniffer and verify what is happening.  You should see the version of TLS in the sniffer and verify what you wrote is correct.

Comment: Your problem is that you are calling the next `BeginWrite` before waiting for the previous one to finish. `async` `await` is *far far* better at controlling how these callbacks work, and you should switch to using that. You are also missing a bunch of `using` blocks to dispose stuff.

Comment: I'm using SslProtocols.Tls12, despite the title.  Any example client code using async await? I've looked and can only find fragments. Thanks for the comments guys.